# The CheckBox attached to Datagridview is automatically checked

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have added a new column called `Sales` to my DataGridView.
Where I want to run the insert operation by entering the number of cells.

The problem is, I don't just have to write the number in the `Sales` Column,
I have to select the CheckBox immediately.

I want the checkbox in DataGridviewColumn to be automatically checked when I input any number into my `Sales` Column.
Is it possible? Thanks in advance to the experienced.

[image]

Comment: Assuming the grid has NO data source, then you could wire up the grid’s `CellValueChanged` event to set the check box to checked. If the grid DOES use a data source, then, you may be able to have the check box checked/unchecked automatically through the data source. Example, if the data source is a `DataTable`, then an `ExpressionColumn` would enable the check box to be set automatically when the “sale” value changes. Pick your own poison.

Comment: You need to specify what is source of data of your DataGridView. You can replicate the same functionality of an Expression added to a Column that @JohnG mentioned, to a class object, using the property setter. It's preferable to automate this procedure than resorting to event handlers. -- Not clear what *Where I want to run the insert operation by entering the number of cells* means.